# Assigning binary data from datatable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to get binarydata from `DataTable` to a byte array. 
But the below code returns

> *cannot convert source type 'string' to target type 'byte[]'*

```
DataTable dataTable = DB.GetData("SELECT * FROM StackOverflow WHERE Id = '" + id + "'");

byte[] byteArray = null;


if(dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   byteArray = dataTable.Rows[0]["BinaryData"].ToString());
}
```

How can I get binaryData from StackOverflow table?

```
StackOverflow table 
----------------------
Id    int
BinaryData  varbinary(max)
```

Comment: Can you show your table schema ?

Comment: What are you calling `ToString` when you don't want a string? And please don't build SQL like that... use parameterized SQL instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `.ToString()`, you will *get a string*; instead, simply cast:

```
byteArray = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[0]["BinaryData"];
```

However, there's no need for a `DataTable` here. Personally, I'd just use:

```
var byteArray = conn.Query<byte[]>(
    "SELECT BinaryData FROM StackOverflow WHERE Id=@id",
    new {id}).FirstOrDefault();
```

using dapper, or just `ExecuteScalar` with ADO.NET:

```
byte[] byteArray;
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT BinaryData FROM StackOverflow WHERE Id=@id";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id",id);
   byteArray = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion resulted in unexpected token errors for me. I had to write it as: [byte[]] byteArray = dataTable.Rows[0]["BinaryData"];